# cURL: Connection refused on request from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: php, http, curl, https

I'm trying to send a api request from HTTPS connection to HTTP using cURL in php. But every time i get `Failed to connect to MY_URL: Connection refused`.

This is my code

```
<?php

$tok_url = "URL";
        $token_post = array(
            'username' => "username",
            'password' => "password"
        );

        $curl_log = fopen("malinda/curl.txt", 'rw');

        $curl = curl_init();
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_PORT => "8069",
            CURLOPT_URL => $tok_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => 1,
            CURLOPT_STDERR          => $curl_log,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $token_post,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("cache-control: no-cache")
        );

        curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        print_r($err);

        if ($err) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return json_decode($response);
        }
```

Also I couldn't find the error log.

How can i solve this.

Comment: if you are expecting redirects, you should also set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1`

Comment: what's the remote url?

Comment: it's my company's server url

Comment: "Connection refused"  explained: https://serverfault.com/a/725263

Comment: Thank you but i think the problem is, I'm sending request from HTTPS to HTTP ? It's working fine with HTTP to HTTP